# export database to csv in laravel won't work , "the site can't be reach"

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, export-to-csv

I have some code like this in my controller "UserController.php" to export from the model database to CSV.

when I use die dump `dd($id,$performance);` data that I want to export its looks fine...

die dump img

[image]

but when I click the export button, it didn't work

the button code

```
 <span data-href="{{ route('user/export', $user->id) }}" id="export" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" onclick="exportTasks(event.target);">Export</span>
```

the javascript

```
<script>
        function exportTasks(_this) {
            let _url = $(_this).data('href');
            window.location.href = _url;
        }
    </script>
```

my controller export method

```
public function exportCsv(Request $request , User $user)
{
    $date = \Carbon\Carbon::today();
    $id = $request->id;
    $performance = Performance::where('user_id', '=', $id)
                                    ->get();
    $count = 1;
                                
    $fileName = 'performance.csv';
        
    $headers = array(
        "Content-type"        => "text/csv",
        "Content-Disposition" => "attachment; filename=$fileName",
        "Pragma"              => "no-cache",
        "Cache-Control"       => "must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0",
        "Expires"             => "0"
        );

    $columns = array('No', 'User_ID', 'Username', 'No Order', 'Update Status','Tanggal');

    $callback = function() use($performance, $columns) {
    $file = fopen('php://output', 'w');
    fputcsv($file, $columns);

    foreach ($performance as $pr) {
        $row['No']  = $count++;
        $row['User_ID']    = $pr->user_id;
        $row['ID_Moban']    = $pr->id_moban;
        $row['Username']  = $pr->user_name;
        $row['No Order']  = $pr->no_order;
        $row['Update Status']  = $pr->update_status;
        $row['Tanggal']  = $pr->created_at;

        fputcsv($file, array($row['No'], $row['User_ID'], $row['ID_Moban'], $row['Username'], $row['No Order'], $row['Update Status'], $row['Tanggal']));
    }

    fclose($file);
    };

    //dd($id,$performance);

    return response()->stream($callback, 200, $headers);
}
```

my routes

```
Route::get('user/{id}/export',  [UserController::class, 'exportCsv'])->name('user/export');
```

the error message looks like this

[image]

Comment: Not sure this is the reason or not, but the column count in your csv header row and the data rows has mismatching count. header row lack column `ID_Moban` which is present in your data rows.

Comment: If you return 'hello' at the top of your function do you see hello?  if so, then it may be an issue with your headers and stream.

Comment: try a simple csv export as seen here https://beyondco.de/blog/exporting-laravel-models-to-csv-and-xls  just to be sure it works before trying your real data.

Comment: thanks for answering this question guys, but I am already fix the code, and it works... :)